# VS 2012 C++ crash in Release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Recently I've converted a big C++(MFC) solution from VS2010 to VS2012.
And I've got app crash in Release confguration. After some investigation I located the line which lead to crash. It's in function like this:

```
void CMyWnd::Foo()
{
     if (!m_sub_wnd.GetSafeHwnd())
         return;

     // some other code goes here
     // here used m_sub_wnd and another member m_data
}
```

In Release mode disasm shows the following code for first condition:

```
if (!m_sub_wnd.GetSafeHwnd())
00000001405F6E30  add         rcx,260h  
00000001405F6E37  je          CMyWnd::Foo+0DBh  (01405F6F0Bh)  
00000001405F6E3D  push        rsi  
00000001405F6E3E  sub         rsp,30h  
00000001405F6E42  cmp         qword ptr [rcx+40h],0  
00000001405F6E47  mov         rsi,rcx  
00000001405F6E4A  je          CMyWnd::Foo+0D6h (01405F6F06h)  
return;
```

It seems "add rcx,260h" changes this pointer in any case and other code worked with corrupted this pointer.
I'm not familiar with asm. Is it right or I missed something? If it seems to be C++ compiler bug I'll report problem to Microsoft support.

### Update:

When I added to my function dump of "this" pointer - crash disapeared.

```
void CMyWnd::Foo()
{
00000001405F6BE0  mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],rbx  
00000001405F6BE5  push        rsi  
00000001405F6BE6  sub         rsp,30h  
    if (!m_sub_wnd.GetSafeHwnd())
00000001405F6BEA  lea         rbx,[rcx+260h]  
00000001405F6BF1  mov         rsi,rcx  
00000001405F6BF4  test        rbx,rbx  
00000001405F6BF7  je          CMyWnd::Foo+101h (01405F6CE1h)  
00000001405F6BFD  cmp         qword ptr [rbx+40h],0  
00000001405F6C02  je          CMyWnd::Foo+101h (01405F6CE1h)  
        return;

    s << this << endl;
00000001405F6C08  mov         rdx,rcx  
00000001405F6C0B  lea         rcx,[s (0140D16320h)]  
00000001405F6C12  mov         qword ptr [this],rbp  
00000001405F6C17  mov         qword ptr [rsp+50h],r14  
00000001405F6C1C  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (01409325A0h)]  
00000001405F6C22  mov         rdx,qword ptr [__imp_std::endl (01409326D8h)]  
00000001405F6C29  mov         rcx,rax  
00000001405F6C2C  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (0140932700h)]
```

Comment: You tried a full rebuild after switching to VS2012? If yes, the problem might be somewhere else, e.g. m_sub_wnd.GetSafeHwnd() works correctly but the pointer it returns has been deleted somewhere. Try to make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), please. Sometimes this helps to get an understanding of the real problem.

Comment: Highly unlikely it's a compiler bug. Not enough information to really help you here. Perhaps the entire object `m_sub_wnd` is null or invalid? Which line of assembly caused the exception? What were the register values?

Comment: You can try to compile your project in 'Release With Debug Info' configuration and then run it in debugger.

Comment: Offsetting the *this* pointer is not abnormal, common in multiple inheritance.  It is however the JE instruction after it that's nonsense.  Unless your code snippet is incomplete and the compiler re-ordered instructions for an if() statement that appears above the quoted statement and that we can't see.  The likelier scenario.  If not then you do need Microsoft Support to help you.

Comment: The JE is most likely from an inlined `GetSafeHwnd`, which probably starts with `if (this == NULL)`. Just goes to show why such a check is nonsensical and calling a member on a null pointer is undefined behavior no matter how "harmless" it appears.